Spring HTTP Interface - comma separated list of parameter values
I have the following @HttpExchange in Spring:
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.service.annotation.GetExchange;

...

    @GetExchange("/foo/bar")
    List<Baz> items(
            @RequestParam(name = "ids") List<String> ids
    );

When I execute it, ids are sent like this:
ids=1&ids=2&...
However, I need them to be sent as follows:
ids=1,2,...
I wonder if there is a Spring native way to send them as comma-separated values.
Currently, when I call this method, I need to prepare IDs in the following way:
String.join(",", ids);


I'd recommend following the HTTP idiom.  You don't need them to be CSV format.

@duffymo, it's not my API design; I just need to consume it; BTW, what is the HTTP idiom for multiple values inside a single parameter?

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html

You can try register converter from String to List. Here you can see how:
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter
import org.springframework.format.FormatterRegistry
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer

@Configuration
class WebRequestConverter : WebMvcConfigurer {

    override fun addFormatters(registry: FormatterRegistry) {
        registry.addConverter(StringToListConverter())
    }

    class StringToListConverter : Converter<String, List<String>> {
        override fun convert(source: String): List<String> {
            return source.split(",")
        }
    }
}


like the idea, however it applies this convention globally...

You can simply take String as input, and use split() function to get all ids.
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.service.annotation.GetExchange;

@GetExchange("/foo/bar")
List<Baz> items(
        @RequestParam(name = "ids") String idStr
) {
   List<String> ids = idStr.split(",");
   ...
  ;


This method is part of an interface which will generate a dynamic HTTP client. This won't work with that.
